# Passing float to a nested for loop and storing output

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I have a strong background in Matlab, and I am trying to switch to python. I am trying to write a nested for loop with numpy array and storing output values.

My code reads like:

```
import numpy as np
import math

# T parameter
kk = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
print(len(kk))

# V parameter
pp = np.arange(1, 5, 1)
print(len(pp))

a = len(kk)
b = len(pp)

P = np.zeros((a,b))


for T in kk:
    print(T)
    for V in pp:
        print(V)
        P = math.exp(-T*V/10)

print(P)
```

**Explanation/Question**

1. *kk*, *pp* are the vectors. In for loop(s) correct values of T and V parameters are being called. However, values of *P* are not being stored.
2. I tried the following change `P[T][V] = math.exp(-T*V/10)`, I get the following error: *IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices*

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My experience with MATLAB is a bit dated.  In those old days we tried to avoid iterative calculations, since they were slow.  Instead we tried to work with the whole matrix.  But I hear newer MATLAB does various forms of `jit` compilation, making loops acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code you define `P` as a 2d array.  But the loop you assign the scalar result of the `math.exp` expression to that variable.  That replaces the original `P` value, and also replaces the value calculated in the previous loop.  This kind of loop doesn't work in MATLAB does it?  Don't you have to assign the scalar value to some 'slot' in `P`?

```
P = np.zeros((a,b))
for T in kk:
    print(T)
    for V in pp:
        print(V)
        P = math.exp(-T*V/10)
```

A better way:

```
In [301]: kk = np.arange(0,20,0.1)                                                            
In [302]: kk.shape                                                                            
Out[302]: (200,)
In [303]: pp = np.arange(1, 5,1)                                                              
In [304]: pp.shape                                                                            
Out[304]: (4,)
```

In `numpy` we prefer to use fast whole-array methods.  Here I use `broadcasting` to perform an `outer` like calculation of `kk` with `pp`.

```
In [305]: P = np.exp(-kk[:,None]*pp/10)                                                       
In [306]: P.shape                                                                             
Out[306]: (200, 4)
```

(I believe MATLAB added `broadcasting` in recent years; `numpy` has had it from the beginning.)

Comparing this with the iterative version:

```
In [309]: P1 = np.zeros((200,4)) 
     ...: for i in range(0,len(kk)): 
     ...:     for j in range(0,len(pp)): 
     ...:         T = kk[i] 
     ...:         V = pp[j] 
     ...:         P1[i,j] = math.exp(-T*V/10) 
     ...:                                                                                     
In [310]: P1.shape                                                                            
Out[310]: (200, 4)
In [311]: np.allclose(P,P1)                                                                   
Out[311]: True
```

A cleaner way of writing indexed iteration in Python is with `enumerate`:

```
In [312]: P1 = np.zeros((200,4)) 
     ...: for i,T in enumerate(kk): 
     ...:     for j,V in enumerate(pp): 
     ...:         P1[i,j] = math.exp(-T*V/10)
```

Comment: @hapaulj: Thank you for the detailed answer, it took me a while to grasp it. To be honest, my mind is blown off, particularly with this `P = np.exp(-kk[:,None]*pp/10)`. So let me state here what I understood (please correct me if I am wrong): 1) This line is kind of an direct vector operation without needing a for loop, 2) with `np.exp` I am able to see more digits of P. 3) `:` represents all values of `kk` in P array, which is multiplied by each value of pp.  I couldn't fully understand 1) what is the role of `None`, 2) Is there a possibility to extend this to 3D array? Thanks :)

Comment: I agree with you, in Matlab, we do need to define the location `P[i,j]` to store the values of computed value. I tried to perform that as well, but I couldn't pass `floats` to for loop (which is obvious). Your last 4 lines of code explained me how to do that in more Pythonic way ! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the line where you mentioned trying `P[T][V] = math.exp(-T*V/10)`, you might also be interested in this option:

```python
import numpy as np
import math

# T parameter
kk = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
print(len(kk))

# V parameter
pp = np.arange(1, 5, 1)
print(len(pp))

a = len(kk)
b = len(pp)

P = np.zeros((a,b))

for i in range(0,len(kk)):
    for j in range(0,len(pp)):
        T = kk[i]
        V = pp[j]
        P[i][j] = math.exp(-T*V/10)

        # you can also simply do this:
        #P[i][j] = math.exp(-kk[i]*pp[j]/10)
```

Although it's straightforward, it's not particularly clean. Since you mentioned that you're switching to python, I'd take a look at hpaulj's answer for a more thorough explanation and as well as a nice alternative to iterating through  arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is so straight forward.

Comment: Old time `numpy` users don't like to see `P[i][j]` syntax.  We prefer `P[i, j]`.  Here both work, but the former suggests the programmer is still thinking terms of nested lists.

Comment: @hpaulj For me at least the ```P[i][j]``` syntax is a holdover from C/C++, but I do agree that it is not very "pythonic". I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dictionary if you want to see the `keys` and `values` per your comment. This might make more sense actually. I would recommend against a plethora of dynamically created variables, as with a dictionary, you can call the entire dictionary OR specific values, which you could store as variables later anyway. Obviously, it depends on the scope of your project and what solution makes sense, but you could also turn the dictionary into a `pandas` `dataframe` with `pd.DataFrame()` for analysis, so it gives you flexibility. You said you are new to python, so you might want to check out pandas if you haven't heard of it, but you probably have as it is one of or the most popular library.

```
import numpy as np
import math

P_dict = {}

# T parameter
kk = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
# print(len(kk))

# V parameter
pp = np.arange(1, 5, 1)
# print(len(pp))

a = len(kk)
b = len(pp)

P = np.zeros((a,b))


for T in kk:
#     print(T)
    for V in pp:
#         print(V)
        P = math.exp(-T*V/10)
        key = f'{T},{V}'
        value = P
        P_dict[key] = value

print(P_dict)
```

This is how you would call a value in the dict based on the key.

```
P_dict['19.900000000000002,3']
```

You can also edit this line of code to whatever format you want: `key = f'{T},{V}'` and call the key acording to the format as I have done in my example.

Output:
`0.002554241418992996`

Either way, a list or a dict prints some interesting python abstract art!

Comment: Thank for the answer. However, it is difficult to see for which T values, values of P being printed. Is there a way to find that?

Comment: @pukumarathe see my edit post shortly. The alternative is a dictionary.

Comment: @pukumarathe I have updated my answer. I think a dict makes sens for your needs. I have deleted the part of my answer that creates a list, so the answer is more focused.

Comment: no problem @pukumarathe I'm but not sure you saw it, but I have updated my explanation as to why a dictionary might be a better solution for you, and feel free to upvote if helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think, dictionary will be useful for me in a different project. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote your answer, for that matter any answers, because my reputation isn’t high enough. As soon as I reach that number, i will upvote the same. Thanks again!